# How to customize minimized icon?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-foundation

Using `setApplicationIconImage` I was able to change the icon in the dock and command+tab menu. However it's not taking affect on the minimized window icons. Please see image below. The red arrow points to the minimized icon, it's not matching the first icon we see in the command+tab or the dock pointed to with blue arrow.

[image]

How can I make this minimized window icon match my `setApplicationIconImage` icon?

Comment: That minimized icon sure looks like the icon for Mozilla's Firefox browser to me. Is your application a custom version of Firefox?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann thanks for comment! Yep it is firefox's icon, im actually writing an addon for firefox and my addon is changing the icon. https://github.com/Noitidart/Profilist/issues/18#issuecomment-46795390 shows how i accomplished it on windows